# Zombie process during start

Tags: 12.04, grub2, login

My laptop (12.04 and W7) will not start in Ubuntu any more. The login screen (black) appears after Grub.

It says. When I enter my name and password I enter "a terminal" and I can't get any further. The message I get sometimes is that there is a Zombie process running. As I try to kill that (which i can't) and terminate the child (never thought I would write this down) nothing happens.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try to Boot with an older Kernel Version.

Comment: And than? Update to latest kernel?

Answer (score 1):

It worked: booted an older kernel and then installed video drivers, problem fixed

Comment: It happened to me sometime back. If I remember clearly, I restored the older kernel, and did, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -f && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. It fixed several broken packages.